# Stabilizers and equivariant maps

Tags: group-theory, equivariant-maps

Suppose $G$ acts on a set $X$ and $Y$ and let $f:X \to Y$ be a equivariant map.

We immediately have that 
$$\text{stab}_{G}(x) \subseteq \text{stab}_{G}(f(x)) $$
as if $g \in \text{stab}_{G}(x)$ then $f(x) = f(gx) = g f(x)$ so $g \in \text{stab}_{G}(f(x))$.

If we restrict the action to a group $H \subseteq G$ we have that 
$$\text{stab}_{H}(x) = H \cap \text{stab}_{G}(x).$$

My question is: How would one find the largest subgroup $H$ such that 
$$\text{stab}_{H}(x) \trianglelefteq \text{stab}_{H}(f(x))$$
for all $x \in X$?

Clearly if $H=Z(G)$ the condition holds as then the stabilizers become commutative and the subgroup condition proven earlier implies normality.

Comment: Perhaps it is the normalizer in  $G$ of ${\rm stab}_G(x)$.

Comment: I see why this would be sufficient for $\text{stab}_{H}(x)\trianglelefteq \text{stab}_{H}(f(x))$ for a single $x \in X$ but I see no reason it would imply $\text{stab}_{H}(x)\trianglelefteq \text{stab}_{H}(f(x))$ for all $x \in X$?

Comment: It was my understanding that although stabilizer groups on elements in a single orbit are related by conjugation the stabilisers of elements in different orbits are independent. This makes is surprising that a largest $H$ could be found without referencing at least one element of each orbit.